# months after current fiscal

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, date-arithmetic

I have table called `t1` with `PERIOD` column. I want to find the number of months since current fiscal `jun-2014` - currently 11 (because it's may). If this condition fails then do something.

How can I do this check:

```
select PERIOD from t1;

  PERIOD 
8/31/2014
6/30/2015
10/31/2014
1/31/2015
3/31/2015
9/30/2014

select  count(PERIOD) from  t1
where trunc(PERIOD)>'30-JUNE-2014';
```

o/p of the above query is 6 ,the correct answer should be 11 ,so the condn has failed .my expected output is if the condition failed trigger something

I'm not sure whether this is correct. I'm using 11g Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

> trunc(PERIOD)>'30-JUNE-2014'

- `'30-JUNE-2014'` is a string. You are comparing a **DATE** with a **STRING**. You need **TO_DATE** to convert the string into date.
- **`TRUNC`** truncates the **time portion** from the date, you should use it ONLY if you want to neglect the time portion.
- You must avoid the **locale-specific NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE dependency**.

```
SELECT COUNT(PERIOD)
   FROM t1
 WHERE PERIOD > TO_DATE('30-JUN-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH');
```

Comment: based on the records on my table i get the count as 12,it has to be 11.how can I perform the check.if the condn failed then do something

Comment: @user3452154 I don't have yyour data. Edit your question and add your expected output based on your input data.